# getResource("path") works in Intellij but not in jar file

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have a text file I need to read, where I use this LoC that works in Intellij but not in the packaged jar file. I don't rather not use the InputStreamReader as I have made an own Reader class. I read from a file in "src/controllers/MenuController", and the WorldState1.txt is in "src/files/worldstate1.txt".

```
GameReader.readFile(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("files/WorldState1.txt").getPath());
```

Is there something I'm missing or have I misunderstood getResource()?

Comment: Well is `files/WorldState1.txt` in the classpath of your JAR file?  Type `jar -tvf your_jar.jar` and see if it is there.

Comment: Also, tell us about your project, and if you are using a framework such as Maven or Gradle.

Comment: jar -tvf gives me a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Semesteroppgave.jar I'm not using any frameworks, built in JavaFX

Comment: Just run that in the same place as `Semesteroppgave.jar`.  Does it run?

Comment: it says files/WorldState1.txt, so I guess it is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the problem was that I didn't use the correct path. What I ended up doing was

```
 GameReader.readFile(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("WorldState1.txt"));
```

I also had to read the file using

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

instead of a Files.readAllLines(); since it now is a stream. Hope this helps anyone else dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem... The files were in my jar file, pathed as expected.  The project ran fine from within the IDE (Intellij), but the Jar would fail to load some of my assets.

The problem was, my development workstation is a Windows machine, which isn't case-sensitive for directories and filenames, but the file-access mechanism Java uses to read files within the JAR is case-sensitive.

So, where I had "data/zones/dynamic/myart.png" which worked when running from the IDE, the JAR wouldn't work until I changed it to read "data/Zones/Dynamic/myart.png"... just those two capitalization errors made the resource un-findable...  Folks who dev on Linux don't have that problem, since the whole system is case-sensitive, they're used to being careful about such things.

So, if your code can't find your assets when running from JAR, but the files are there, double-check the path/filename for correct-case.

Remember: It's easy to check contents of a jar, just rename it as .zip and open/extract.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not recomended to use getClassLoader() anymore since java 9 (or probably since newer version)

If the line of code you provided from MenuController class?
If so `MenuController.class.getResource` or `this.getClass().getResources` point you to its directory: `src/controllers/` and to this path you add `files/WorldState1.txt`. You need to build relative path by using `..` or use another "startingpoint" like `SomeClassInSRCFolder.class.getResource("files/WorldState1.txt)`

Comment: Isn't `getResource` always relative to the start of the class path?  And where did the OP say it was using Java 9?

Comment: I am using Java 10 btw, didn't know it was deprecated

Comment: It wasnt deprecated, it changes for modularity and could cause problem coz it it.

Comment: So if I'm in files/GameReader, then the right way to get WorldState's path would be this.getClass().getResource(".WorldState1.txt") since WorldState is in files as well. This doesn't seem to work though

Comment: the filename is "WorldState1.txt" not ".WorldState1.txt"